# View event reflected in collection convention

Tags: backbone.js

What is the best way to remove a model from a collection that has been removed in the DOM. Let me ask a better question, how do I keep views in sync with a collection?

Answer (score 0):

remove the view first, while removing execute

```
 this.model.collection.remove(this.model);
```

you can check with conditions to whether current view has a model, and that model has a collection etc before you execute the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the backbone [Todos](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/todos.html) example application. This keeps view state up to date with collection.

Pass models to any view created like so:

```
var someView = new SomeItemView({ model: modelFromCollection });
```

Then listen to events on that model and react from the view:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
  // listen to other events ...
}
```